# Is this a good circuit to control LED?

Tags: led, mosfet

I'm taking an intro electronics course, and we recently covered MOSFETs.  Would the [circuit below](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/kn8ud4/led-1/) work for controlling a 3W LED? Here is the [part info](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=LZ1-10R200virtualkey62410000virtualkey897-LZ110R200). The LED wants about 1A of current. I'm thinking I can use the variable resistor to set \$V_{gs}\$ on the MOSFET so that it allows 1A to flow to the LED. For the 5V supply I have a computer power supply, so I could actually use other wires and get 3, or 12 V.

[image]

Comment: That is one serious LED.  At first I thought you made a mistake saying it wants 1A (most LEDs run fine with 10 or 20 ma or less).  From the datasheet, the LED has a forward voltage Vf of 2.5v.  If you are going to run this off a 5v supply, you have to have a series resistor to drop the other 2.5v.  With a 1A current, this calls for a 2.5 ohm resistor!  Best to use two 5 ohm 2W resistors in parallel.

Comment: Why do you want to couple the LED forward voltage into Vgs?  Why not use an open drain configuration and sink the current through the LED?

Comment: @DeanB: A source follower is actually a good idea since it will give you more predictable adjustment accross the range.  However, there should still be a resistor in series with the LED.  Also consider heat dissipation in both the resistor and the FET.

Comment: @OlinLathrop:  Interesting.  I haven't played with source followers before, but after researching a bit I now see the benefits.  Thanks for the perspective - it's always fun to learn new things.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I now see that I need to be more efficient and not dissipate the energy in the MOSFET or the resistor.  So I need to read up about this buck converter mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can make this work. As tcrosley points out, you'll end up with 1A @ 2.5V across your FET so you need to dissipate 2.5W or so (M1 will need a heatsink).

A more efficient circuit (less heatsinks) would be to use a buck converter and measure the led current with a sense resistor. Then use feedback to set the buck voltage according to the brightness you want.

If you are stuck with the 5V supply then another option is to use two of your leds in series. That way you get some more light.

Comment: Actually there won't be that much voltage drop across the FET, assuming its Rds is under 100 mOhm or so.  The 5V will be split between the series resistor I suggested and the LED.

Comment: agreed for your circuit. My circuit doesn't have the series power resistors and uses the FET as a linear regulator. Of course, once you are doing that you might as well use a real adjustable linear regulator. Either way, the main point here is that he as another 2.5V at 1A to eat up. So I'd say make a switcher or just throw in another LED.